# How does Leadership work for a Vigilante?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

I’m interested in playing a Vigilante character specializing in [Leadership](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership/). The Vigilante class has the [Dual Identity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Vigilante/#Dual_Identity_Ex) extraordinary ability, which gives them a social identity (Bruce Wayne, Peter Parker, Clark Kent or Oliver Queen) and a vigilante identity (Batman, Spiderman, Superman or the Green Arrow, respectively). Amazingly, these two identities can have different (but not opposite) alignments and are often treated as entirely different people. But how would this work with Leadership?

**Would a Vigilante have a single Leadership score (as implied by RAW by lack of a rule), or would the Vigilante have two *separate* Leadership scores (as implied thematically): one for the vigilante identity and one for the social identity?**

**IF** the Vigilante’s identities have *separate* Leadership scores...:

- ...How would this depend on feats/traits that affect the Leadership score, such as certain variants of the Noble Scion feat, the Racial Ties (human) trait, and/or the Natural-Born Leader trait? Do these affect only the social identity, the Vigilante identity, or could they affect both?
- ...Could the factors influencing the Leadership score stack for characters (e.g. PCs, cohorts, followers) who know the Vigilante’s secret? In other words, if the social identity was a person of “great renown” (+2 to Leadership score) and the Vigilante had a stronghold (+2 to Leadership score), would the Vigilante have an effective Leadership score of +4 for people who knew both identities were the same person?

Obviously much of this is at my GM’s discretion, but as a GM myself, I’m curious how others would handle this.

Comment: I edited your tags; leader and minion are about specific game components not generally present in Pathfinder 1e. "Feats" accomplishes recognition that this is about the Leadership feat

Answer (score 3):

### There is no change for the Vigilante, they get only *one* Leadership score.

As far as I can find, there isn't anything mechanical that changes for the feat based on the Vigilante's current identity.

You still get a single cohort, who's the Alfred to your Bruce/Batman. You still accrue bonuses based on your achievements. Base of operations? Well, both identities would probably use it, just with more sneaking (and secret tunnels) involved for one identity or the other. Great renown? As a PC, you're likely to be well know by most people either way(especially once you're high enough level to take Leadership), just probably for different reasons in the different circles they frequent.

Now, I could see a DM ruling that you had to pick one or the other identity for the purposes of the feat, which makes sense, but that would still boil down to mostly a fluff decision, with little game impact, as you're likely to have most of, if not all, the same bonuses in either identity.

I would also like to point out the consequences of having two leadership scores would involve giving the feat even more power than it has already, which is definitely not an intended mechanic.

Comment: Shouldn't Batman's cohort be Robin? I don't know the lore much, that's what I remember from a computer game played, probably, more than 16 years ago. IIRC, Robin could also be a Vigilante in this case...

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy That depends. Batman *always* has Alfred, but he goes through multiple Robins. Really, it could go either way, but I would lean heavily towards Alfred because of that.

Comment: That's what "Caused the death of a cohort" is probably for. :)

Comment: I'd like to point out that *Caused the death of* and *Died while in your service* are not the same thing. Besides, he had Alfred long before he had any of his Robins.

Answer (score 0):

This is really going to depend on your DM. But i could see it going one of two ways:

Either you're made to choose which identity gets the followers, or the followers are split between the two identities with the only exception being your cohort. I'm sure you can trust your cohort with your secret identity, right?

Heck, you may want your cohort to have a secret identity too!